# R read.table csv with classic-mac line endings

Tags: r, csv, line-endings

I have a comma-separated value file that looks like this when I open it in vim:

```
12,31,50,,12^M34,23,45,2,12^M12,31,50,,12^M34,23,45,2,12^M
```

and so forth.  I believe this means my CSV uses CR-only (classic mac) line endings.  R's read.table() function ostensibly requires LF line endings, or some variant thereof.

I know I can preprocess the file, and that's probably what I'll do.

That solution aside: is there a way to import CR files directly into R?  For instance, write.table() has an "eol" parameter one can use to specify the line ending of outputs -- but I don't see a similar parameter for read.table() (cf. http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/read.table.html).

Comment: Or, if R is supposed to be able to handle mac line endings gracefully, I'll know I have another problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R will not recognize "^M" as anything useful.(I suppose it's possible that vim is just showing you a cntrl-M as that character.) If that were in a text-connection-stream R will think it's not a valid escaped-character, since "^" is not used for that purpose. You might need to do the pre-processing, unless you want to pass it through scan() and substitute using gsub():

```
subbed <- gsub("\\^M", "\n", scan(textConnection("12,31,50,,12^M34,23,45,2,12^M12,31,50,,12^M34,23,45,2,12^M"), what="character"))
Read 1 item

> read.table(text=subbed, sep=",")
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1 12 31 50 NA 12
2 34 23 45  2 12
3 12 31 50 NA 12
4 34 23 45  2 12
```

I suppose it's possible that you may need to use "\\m" as the `patt` argument to `gsub`.

A further note: The help page for scan says: "Whatever mode the connection is opened in, any of LF, CRLF or CR will be accepted as the EOL marker for a line and so will match sep = "\n"." So the linefeed character ("\n"if that's what they are) should have been recognized them, since `read.table` is based on `scan`. You should look at ?Quotes for information on escape characters.

If this [vim tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialAdvanced_vi.html) is to be believed those may be DOS-related characters since it offers this advice:

Strip DOS ctrl-M's:

```
:1,$ s/{ctrl-V}{ctrl-M}//
```

Comment: Yeah, ^M is just vim's placeholder for CR.

And, on looking closer at my errors, turns out my problem remained after converting to to LF:  I just needed to set fill=T in the first place :#

Comment: Ah, the old variable length lines problem. The `count.fields` function is good for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is an R native solution that requires no preprocessing or external hacks. You should use the `encoding` input argument to the `read.table` function and set it equal to `"latin1"` for Mac character encoding.

For example, say your file in Mac (^M for return) format is saved as `test.csv`, load as follows:

```
 test <- read.table("./test.csv", sep=",", encoding="latin1")
```

To see what options you can pass the `encoding` argument type [`?Encoding`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Encoding.html) into the R interpreter and you will see `"latin1"`, `"UTF-8"`, `"bytes"` or `"unknown"`are the supported encodings.

This is the best & cleanest way to do this.